# Change <Option> value of <select>

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

At the moment I am using a select tag to display different groups to the user. I then want to use the values in the select tag to change group. For this I am using cookies. My problem is when I refresh the page the select will go back to default value. Is it possible to keep the chosen value until the user wants to change group?

this is what i have:

HTML:

```
<form>
    @if (Model != null)
    {
        <select class="target">
            @foreach (var item in Model.groupmanage)
            {
                <option value="@item.Id" >@item.GroupName</option>

            }


        </select>

    }
```

JQuery:

```
<script>
        //$if (("select").!= )
        $("select").change(function () {
            var groupId = $('.target').find(":selected").val();
            document.cookie = "currentGroup=" + groupId;
            //alert();
        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to set your selected option directly with ASP.NET.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.groupmanage)
{
    if (Response.Cookies("currentGroup") != null && item.Id == Response.Cookies("currentGroup").Value) {
        <option value="@item.Id" selected="selected">@item.GroupName</option>
    }
    else {
        <option value="@item.Id">@item.GroupName</option>
    }
}
```

I didn't test it but it should work. Just tell me if something is wrong with it.

Comment: I get the following error: "non-invocable member cannot be used like a method" this error appears under Cookies.

Comment: `Response.Cookies["currentGroup"]` perhaps?

Comment: @Seb I can' debug it now because I'm currently not on a Computer but I've updated my answer to prevent version incompatibilty issues

Comment: Btw. I'm not sure the cookie value is a string or an object so you may cast it before comparing it with your `item.Id` which you may have to cast too.

Comment: @werner Seems like this could work, but having problems casting it. Any tips?

Comment: You could just cast both (item.Id and cookievalue) to a string

Comment: Thanks! I managed to run with no bugs, however i still have a problem with my select going back to default when page is refreshed. Do you think the value on the option tag inside the if is wrong somehow?